# beatifusoupをimportできないのはなぜ？

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

import BeautifulSoupを実行すると以下のエラーが表示されてしまいます。
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BeautifulSoup'
コマンドプロンプトでpip install [パッケージ]は問題なく実行できて
pip freezeコマンドを実行するとインストールされたパッケージの一覧にbeautifulsoupは表示されています。
どのような原因が考えられますか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python3のようなので、 `pip install beautifulsoup4` をインストールしてください。 `beautifulsoup` (4じゃない方)はPython3で動作しません。

このあたりの話は以下にあります。

- https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html

そして、import文は以下のように書いてください

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

この話は以下にあります

- https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/